# Combine data in oracle without duplicate GRN line

Tags: oracle

eg:Rule: 1 invoice have n D/O, 1 D/O have n GRN 
Table invoice + D/O: (A)

```
Invoice_no  |Line |DO_NUM    |DO_LINE |CUS_PO   |PO_LINE |ITEM      |INV_QTY
8100OPN02173|0001 |2000004479|0001    |20190123 |0001    |HT02Y  NAT|100
8100OPN02173|0002 |2000004479|0001    |20190123 |0001    |HT02Y  NAT|100
8100OPN02173|0003 |2000004479|0001    |20190123 |0001    |HT02Y  NAT|300
```

....
Table GRN + D/O: (B)

```
DO_NUM    |DO_LINE|GRN_NUM |GRN_LINE|BASE_COST_AMT|COST_AMT|QTY
2000004479|0001   |70001802|0007    |19560690     |837     |100
2000004479|0001   |70001896|0001    |19577430     |837     |100
2000004479|0001   |70002020|0001    |11082286     |476.76  |300
```

....

Now i use query:

```
Select Distinct * 
from A 
left join B 
where 
a.do_num = b. do_num
and a.do_line = b.do_line
and a.inv_qty = b.qty
```

but result show not what i want (about technical is right) because invoice line 1 don't have GRN 70001896 and line 2 don't have GRN 70001802. Line 4,5 does not exist in reality. How can fix it?

```
Invoice_no  |Line |DO_NUM    |DO_LINE |CUS_PO   |PO_LINE |ITEM      |INV_QTY |GRN_NUM |GRN_LINE|BASE_COST_AMT|COST_AMT|QTY
8100OPN02173|0001 |2000004479|0001    |20190123 |0001    |HT02Y  NAT|100     |70001802|0007    |19560690     |837     |100
8100OPN02173|0002 |2000004479|0001    |20190123 |0001    |HT02Y  NAT|100     |70001896|0001    |19577430     |837     |100
8100OPN02173|0003 |2000004479|0001    |20190123 |0001    |HT02Y  NAT|300     |70002020|0001    |11082286     |476.76  |300
8100OPN02173|0001 |2000004479|0001    |20190123 |0001    |HT02Y  NAT|100     |70001896|0001    |19577430     |837     |100
8100OPN02173|0002 |2000004479|0001    |20190123 |0001    |HT02Y  NAT|100     |70001802|0007    |19560690     |837     |100
```

I want data like that:

```
Invoice_no  |Line |DO_NUM    |DO_LINE |CUS_PO   |PO_LINE |ITEM      |INV_QTY |GRN_NUM |GRN_LINE|BASE_COST_AMT|COST_AMT|QTY
8100OPN02173|0001 |2000004479|0001    |20190123 |0001    |HT02Y  NAT|100     |70001802|0007    |19560690     |837     |100
8100OPN02173|0002 |2000004479|0001    |20190123 |0001    |HT02Y  NAT|100     |70001896|0001    |19577430     |837     |100
8100OPN02173|0003 |2000004479|0001    |20190123 |0001    |HT02Y  NAT|300     |70002020|0001    |11082286     |476.76  |300
```

...

Comment: Please do not re-edit your post to remove the formatting of the data. When you do that, you make it unreadable and less likely for us to help you. Also, please update your question to include the logic driving the results you are trying to get.

Comment: @boneist thank you for support. I don't know how to interpret the question for brevity. My mean: it will pick up data in table B and match it to table A with rule (1 time - finding the first satisfactory data will stop not finding other data). And if table A have 3 lines then result have only 3 lines not more 5,6 lines...

Comment: With your join conditions, the first two rows in A each match both of the first two rows in B, so the result you get is right. What logic are you using (as a human for now) to decide that they should only match one of those, and which one that should be? (Please edit your question to explain, don't put everything in comments)

Comment: "invoice line 1 don't have GRN 70001896 and line 2 don't have GRN 70001802" - but ***why***? I can't see anything in your data to say that is the case. What links an invoice line number to a specific `grn_num`? (I can make up a way to get the result you want for this sample data, but without knowing your actual logic and more about your data there's no way to tell if that's right generally...)

Comment: Table A record invoice. User can pickup D/O for invoice (store in tbl A). Tbl B record GRN. User can pickup GRN for D/O (store in tbl B). Now i need connect A with B and logic is GRN not duplicate ( actual is line of GRN not duplicate). But my query still show duplicate GRN --> total amount wrong in report.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to say this. Your data model does not allow you to see which `grn_num` (if any) is associated with which invoice line number. If you have logic outside the database to say how they are connected then you need to explain that (but really it should be in the data model anyway).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in your data model to associate a specific row in B to a specific row in A, when all the join conditions are met. The first two rows in A match both of the first two rows in B because they all have the same `do_num`, `do_line` and quantity. There is nothing to say that invoice line 0001 is linked to `grn_num` 70001802 but not to 70001896. (Also not sure why you seem to be storing numbers as zero-padded strings, but hopefully you have a reason for that.)

Based on the limited data you could get the result you want by making some assumptions - specifically here that you want ascending `grn_num` values linked to ascending invoice line numbers, and there are always going to be the same number of A and B rows for the join conditions you showed (the left join means it will still return data if there are fewer Bs than As, but some will be incomplete rows; and if there are more Bs than As then some B data will be missing).

With those assumptions, or your own, you could add a pseudocolumn to the data in each table using an analytic function like `row_number()`, essentially with the assumptions in the `partition by` clause, something like:

```
select a.*,
  row_number() over (partition by do_num, do_line, inv_qty order by "Line") as rn
from a
```

and

```
  select b.*,
    row_number() over (partition by do_num, do_line, qty order by grn_num) as rn
  from b
```

and then join the results of those as subqueries (inline views):

```
select a."Invoice_no", a."Line", a.do_num, a.do_line, a.cus_po, a.po_line, a.item, a.inv_qty,
  b.grn_num, b.grn_line, b.base_cost_amt, b.cost_amt, b.qty
from (
  select a.*,
    row_number() over (partition by do_num, do_line, inv_qty order by "Line") as rn
  from a
) a
left join (
  select b.*,
    row_number() over (partition by do_num, do_line, qty order by grn_num) as rn
  from b
) b
on b.do_num = a.do_num
and b.do_line = a.do_line
and b.qty = a.inv_qty
and b.rn = a.rn
```

With your sample data in CTEs:

```
-- CTEs for sample data
with a ("Invoice_no", "Line", do_num, do_line, cus_po, po_line, item, inv_qty) as (
  select 8100OPN02173, '0001', 2000004479, '0001', 20190123, '0001', 'HT02Y  NAT', 100 from dual
  union all
  select 8100OPN02173, '0002', 2000004479, '0001', 20190123, '0001', 'HT02Y  NAT', 100 from dual
  union all
  select 8100OPN02173, '0003', 2000004479, '0001', 20190123, '0001', 'HT02Y  NAT', 300 from dual
), b (do_num, do_line, grn_num, grn_line, base_cost_amt, cost_amt, qty) as (
  select 2000004479, '0001', 70001802, '0007', 19560690, 837, 100 from dual
  union all
  select 2000004479, '0001', 70001896, '0001', 19577430, 837, 100 from dual
  union all
  select 2000004479, '0001', 70002020, '0001', 11082286, 476.76, 300 from dual
)
-- actual query
select a."Invoice_no", a."Line", a.do_num, a.do_line, a.cus_po, a.po_line, a.item, a.inv_qty,
  b.grn_num, b.grn_line, b.base_cost_amt, b.cost_amt, b.qty
from (
  select a.*,
    row_number() over (partition by do_num, do_line, inv_qty order by "Line") as rn
  from a
) a
left join (
  select b.*,
    row_number() over (partition by do_num, do_line, qty order by grn_num) as rn
  from b
) b
on b.do_num = a.do_num
and b.do_line = a.do_line
and b.qty = a.inv_qty
and b.rn = a.rn
/
```

```
Invoice_no Line     DO_NUM DO_L     CUS_PO PO_L ITEM          INV_QTY    GRN_NUM GRN_ BASE_COST_AMT   COST_AMT        QTY
---------- ---- ---------- ---- ---------- ---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---- ------------- ---------- ----------
      8100 0001 2000004479 0001   20190123 0001 HT02Y  NAT        100   70001802 0007      19560690        837        100
      8100 0002 2000004479 0001   20190123 0001 HT02Y  NAT        100   70001896 0001      19577430        837        100
      8100 0003 2000004479 0001   20190123 0001 HT02Y  NAT        300   70002020 0001      11082286     476.76        300
```

Whether that approach and those assumptions will work for all your other data is something you will have to verify though.

It would be much simpler if the association was included in your data model, of course...

Comment: Thank you, your query can use in my case.